# 5. 1.1 Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage- InAppPurchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

My app is a social networking app and it cannot be functional without a user account. I gave the user the options to login with Facebook or Custom SignUp, and my app contains InAppPurchase. Apple rejected the app and here is what they said:

> **5. 1.1 Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage**
>
> We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information to purchase non account-based in-app purchase products,
>   which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app
>   content and features that are not associated specifically to the
>   user.
>
> To resolve this issue, please make it clear to the user that
>   registering will enable them to access the content from any of their
>   iOS devices and provide them a way to register at any time, if they
>   wish to later extend access to additional iOS devices.
>
> Please note that although guideline 3.1.2 of the App Store Review
>   Guidelines requires an app to make subscription content available to
>   all the iOS devices owned by a single user, it is not appropriate to
>   force user registration to meet this requirement; such user
>   registration must be made optional.

Please help me with the issue,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, try to provide access to your IAPs and restore button before registration. Create and additional screen, for example.

Comment: Ya, I added IPA button and Restore Button in the home Screen when app launches irrespective of user signedIn or SignUp.
Still Apple rejecting my APP with the same reason.

Comment: What kind of IAP do you use BTW? Some sort of subscription?

Comment: am using non-renewable purchase with 1 year duration.

Comment: Can your app provide any features to meet the second paragraph requirements?

Comment: Same problem here, how did you get to solve it ?

Comment: Hello sir Upload my apps in itunestore bt at time reject apps this issue "please revise the permission modal alert to specify why the app is requesting access to the user's Camera and Photos."

Comment: any idea solve this issue regarding my problem